# How to display a pop up message while a batch script runs?

Tags: batch-file

How can I have my batch file display a pop up message that says loading while it runs the rest of the script. I would like the message to disappear once the batch script is complete. Essentially I am trying to have batch script display a pop up message while files are being copied in the background.

Can this be done? Currently I know I can use something like this for a customized message:

```
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo WScript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "You have 10 seconds to Click 'OK'." ,10 ,"Click OK", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
if %errorlevel%==1 (
  echo You Clicked OK
) else (
  echo The Message timed out.
)
del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

But I would like a pop up message to show until the entire batch script has completed.

Comment: With pure batch scripting? well, no, it can't be done. Batch scripts are not intended for GUI control, so perhaps it's not the right thing for your task...

Comment: Well that can't be right because I can use the code I have above to display a message for 10 seconds, I just need to display something similar up until the last command in the batch file and than disappear itself.

Comment: Well, it borrows message box capabilities from VBScript by creating a temporary VBScript file, executing it and deleting it finally. The batch execution halts until the VBScript script finished. You could use `start ""` cscript ...` to net the VBScript script not wait, but then you had to tell it the status of the batch script process, which will become quite complicated...

Comment: Can the 'status' be once..START hello.exe runs?

Comment: You mean to let VBScript wait until a process `hello.exe` exists? possible, but what if `hello.exe` is run by some other process? I'd rather suggest to use a temporary file (whose path could even be passed to VBScript as command line argument) that is created (or deleted) when the batch task wants VBScript to hide the pop-up message...

Comment: I’m simply testing and practicing for now, can you show me how to have the message display until a process hello.exe exists? I’d really appreciate it

Comment: Sorry, I can't right now...

Comment: Ok, no worries :)

Comment: Do you have some time now? I can’t seem to find anything online about this, any help is appreciated